# How to make a responsive banner?

Tags: responsive-design, banner

How to make a responsive image banner that has image and text layers with absolute positions? My client wants the banner along with the layered text and images to scale down when the screen goes smaller (Please refer to the screenshot below). I am not looking for a slider, this is just a simple banner with layers. My client has different banners(with layers) on every page, their website used to be non-responsive and now they want to make it responsive. CSS Media queries will probably not work here since I have to define a new font size and image width for every pixel change on the screen which I believe is time consuming.

[image: a responsive fixed slider]

As you can see, the banner along with the layered texts and images scales down as the screen goes smaller

Link to my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ophLk9pz/1/

HTML:

```
<div class = "banner">
    <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/yfGOPkH.jpg" />
    <img src = "http://www.dummymag.com//media/img/dummy-logo.png" class = "layer-image">
    <h1>Sample Banner Text</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner { width: 1440px; position: relative; }
.banner img { z-index: -1; }
.banner h1 {position: absolute; bottom: 30px; left: 10px; }
.banner p {position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 10px; }
.banner .layer-image { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 150px; z-index: 2; }
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use viewport percentage units on the texts:

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

```
h1 { font-size: 8vw }
```

And images can be scaled like so:

```
img {
   height: auto;
   width:100%;
}
```

If you need fancier scaling methods (contain, cover etc) i believe you need to have the image as a background-image

Comment: Cool, but what about layered images, how can I get them to re-size along with the text and the background image?

Comment: well, the positioning of the images should be done with percentages (left:10%) and the size as mentioned above (width:80%, height:auto)

Comment: heres a starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/ophLk9pz/2/ (but it needs to be cleaned)